# i have already root my nexus4,but why it shows “shell@mako:/ $ ”when i enter command“adb shell”

Tags: root-access

Should not `shell@mako:/ $` be `shell@mako:/ #`? 
Or I haven't root successfully yet? 
How to check whether my nexus4 have root successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rooted or not: Logging in via `adb shell` first brings you to a user-prompt only (connected with the "shell" account). In order to work with root, you need to "escalate" your permissions by invoking `su`:

```
> adb shell
shell@mako:/ $ su
#
```

Apart from that, there are a few [root checker](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=root%20checker) apps available as well...

Comment: Alternatively, re-starting adb as root via `adb root` will  start the shell in escalated mode.  This will only work with custom ROMs though, not rooted stock.

Comment: No. This only works with ROMs signed for development (check the error message on stock ;). Or with [adbd Insecure](http://www.appbrain.com/app/%5Broot%5D-adbd-insecure/eu.chainfire.adbd).

Comment: but why it shows `root@android:/ # ` in another phone (Philips) when i enter command `adb shell`?  What's the difference?

Comment: The other phone might be running a developer's ROM with the daemon (`adbd`) running in root mode by default. See my previous comment.